# How to use result of api with actions from Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I'm trying to retrieve user favorites by axios when user is loggedIn.
For that I use Vuejs with Vuex. All about logging process is ok, but about favorites, I'm missing something but I don't know what.

My `store.ts` is like this :

```
export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        user: null,
        token: null,
        favorites: []
    },

    mutations: {
        setUser(state, user) {
            state.user = user;
        },
        setToken(state, token) {
            state.token = token;
        },
        setFavs(state, favorites) {
            state.favorites = favorites;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        getFavorites({ commit }) {
            axios
                .post("URL_HERE", {
                    userId: this.state.user,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    //console.log(res);
                    commit('setFavs', res.data)

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getFavs: (state) => state.favorites
    },
});
```

On my Favorites component I have :

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Favorites",
  data() {
    return {
      favorites: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isLoggedIn"]),
    ...mapGetters({ Favorites: "getFavs" }),
  },
});
```

Then in template :

```
<div v-for="favorite in Favorites" :key="favorite.event_id">
 <li>{{ favorite }}</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch the action in the mounted hook:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Favorites",
  data() {
    return {
      favorites: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isLoggedIn"]),
    ...mapGetters({ Favorites: "getFavs" }),
  },
 methods:{
  ...mapActions(['getFavorites'])//map the actions as you did with getters
 },
 mounted(){
  this.getFavorites();//dispatch the action
},
//or use a watcher
watch:{
isLoggedIn(newVal,oldVal){
  if(newVal){
        this.getFavorites()
   }
}

}
});
```

Comment: Oh ok I get it now ! How to dynamically listen display it instead of "mounted" hook ?

Comment: you could dispatch it using an event like `@click="getFavorites"`

Comment: When I login, I use a mutation to store the user ID. I need to retrieve Favorites only if this one is set

Comment: you could use a watcher as I mentioned in my edited answer

Comment: As simple.. well I think I have to learn more about accessing data
Thanks dude !